# Trigger event on expiry of database entry's date field

Tags: java, mysql

I am using a RDBMS (mysql specifically), and I have a table that contains a date column.

What I would like to know is, how can I trigger an event to occur within my program (I am using Springboot, mysql, Apache Camel and Kafka together) when the date expires (i.e. a certain period of time has elapsed from the date).

Edit: for additional context, I am seeking to implement a reminder system that will fire when a certain time has passed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented a solution by polling the database using camel's quartz2 component, running an sql query to check for entries with expired dates.

The query looks something like this, where you can alter INTERVAL for the amount of time before an entry is expired:

```
"SELECT entryID, submittedDate FROM db.tablename WHERE submittedDate + INTERVAL 7 DAY<= CURDATE()";
```

My camel route :

```
from("quartz2://YourGroup/YourDBpoller?cron=0+0/1+11-18+?+*+MON-FRI")
.to("bean:sqlBean?method=pollDB()").to("jdbc:datasource")
.convertBodyTo(String.class).process(new Processor() { ...})
```

- Begins with the quartz2 component, which triggers periodically
- Sends the sql query string (returned by the bean component)
- Then handles the returned dataset (i.e. the expired entries) within the processor method.

---

In my case I only require the database to be polled once per day, however if real-time monitoring is required then this might not be appropriate.